# If $f(y)−f(x) \le (y−x)^2$ for all $x,y$, then $f$ is a constant function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose that $f(y)-f(x) \leq (y-x)^2 $ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$. Then how can i show $f$ is a constant function.

I encountered this problem reading Calculus book written by Michael Spivak. He said that this would imply that
$|f(y)-f(x)| \leq (y-x)^2$
and I could derive this exchanging y and x. And his final hint was Divide the interval from $x$ to $y$ into $n$ equal pieces.

Comment: Can you take derivatives?

Comment: @LuizCordeiro No. I did not learn derivatives yet in this book.

Comment: Also: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Aren't some absolute values missing in the left part of the inequality?

Comment: @MariosGretsas Just swap $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I know ,i just mentioned it for the sake of completeness

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Thanks very much I will revise my question a bit.

Comment: hint; show the derivative exists at each point and is $0$. Then use the fact that $\mathbb R$ is connected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a, b\in \Bbb R$.
Pick $n\in \Bbb N$ and for $0\le i\le n$, let $x_i=a+i\frac{b-a}n$ (so $x_0=a$, $x_n=b$). Then
$$\begin{align} f(b)-f(a)&=f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})+f(x_{n-1})-f(x_{n-2})+\cdots +f(x_1)-f(x_0)\\
&\le (x_n-x_{n-1})^2+(x_{n-1}-x_{n-2})^2+\cdot +(x_1-x_0)^2\\
&=n\cdot\frac{(b-a)^2}{n^2}\\&=\frac
{(b-a)^2}{n}.\end{align}$$
As $n$ was arbitrary, conclude that $f(b)\le f(a)$. By symmetry, also $f(a)\le f(b)$.

Comment: Wow. This is perfect harmony with spivak's last hint! I really appreciate this answer. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't $x_i=a+i(b-a)/n$.?

Comment: @MariosGretsas I think you are correct. Then $f(b)-f(a) \leq \frac{(b-a)^2}{n}$ right?

Comment: @HenryChoi yes that's it.

Comment: This argument also works for $f(y)-f(x)\le (y-x)^{1+\epsilon}$ with $\epsilon\gt0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \neq y$ and w.l.o.g $x<y$ and $n \in \Bbb{N}$

Then take the partition $P$ of $[x,y]$  such that $P=\{x+\frac{k(y-x)}{n}: k=0,1,2,...,n\}$

Then $$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |f(x+\frac{(k+1)(y-x)}{n})-f(x+\frac{k(y-x)}{n})|$$ $$ \leq \frac{(y-x)^2}{n}$$

from hypothesis. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a little question. I think $k$ starts with 0, not 1. And the last term would be $\frac{(y-x)^2}{n}$. Am I correct?

Comment: You are right..thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dealing with sums: this approach seems to me a bit more elegant.  We claim: If $f(y)-f(x)\leq c\cdot(y-x)^2$ for a non-negative constant $c$, the already $f(y)-f(x)\leq \frac12c\cdot(y-x)^2$.

Prove similar as above:
$$\begin{align}
f(y)-f(x)&=f(y)-f\bigl(\frac12(x+y)\bigr)+f\bigl(\frac12(x+y)\bigr)-f(x)\\
&\leq c\cdot  \left(y-\frac12(x+y)\right)^2+c\cdot \left(\frac12(x+y)-x\right)^2\\
&=c\cdot \left(\frac12(y-x)\right)^2+c\cdot \left(\frac12(x-y)\right)^2\\
&=\frac12 c\cdot(y-x)^2.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: so then $f(x)-f(y) \leq \frac{1}{2^n}$.

Answer (score 1):

From the given,

$$\lim_{y\to x}\left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right|\le \lim_{y\to x}|y-x|=0$$ and the derivative is everywhere zero.

Comment: This would be useful if I could use the concept of the limit. But this problem was posed before introducing analytical concept of the limit. Thanks.